# Arranging Custom Fields in Custom Settings

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, page-layout, customsetting

Is it possible to arrange custom fields in a custom settings object? I have an object in custom settings (`MyCustomSettings__c`) and I'm creating custom fields. I'd like these to be arranged in specific order rather than the arbitrary order they are currently in.

[image]

I know I can make changes to the order of custom fields in page layouts, but this is a custom settings object. Is the same thing possible here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom settings do not support layouts. If you switch to custom metadata types you can define your own layouts. The other benefit of custom metadata types is that you can actually include CMT records/instances in packages and change sets (which isn't possible with custom settings since these are viewed as data, not metadata).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in custom metadata. Custom Settings do not have an option of configuring layouts where as custom metadata has it.